# (WPF) Textbox problem when creating a spell check using hunspell

Tags: wpf

I am trying to create a spellcheck solution using Hunspell.
I want to make it like the spell check function provided by MS.
Richtextbox has already succeeded, but textbox fails to display red underlines in misspelled words.
In other words, I want to know how to make only certain words in a WPF textbox underline red. Please help me...:-(

Comment: I think you will have to take Richtextbox. Textbox is very limited here.

Comment: Even if it's extremely limited, I want to know how. No richtextbox. It must be a textbox.

Comment: Ah, maybe a bit misleading. Very limited in how to display text. I think what you want to do is completely impossible.

Comment: @back: You can use the _TextBlock_. Like:  `<TextBlock Padding="5"><Underline Foreground="Red"> <Run FontFamily="Arial Black" FontSize="16">Spell</Run>
</Underline> <Run Text=" " /> <Run FontFamily="Arial Black" FontSize="16" FontWeight="Bold" DataContext="">check solutions</Run> </TextBlock>`

Comment: thank you i appreciate answer. But I think there is a way. Microsoft used a red underline in the textbox for misspelled words.

Comment: @Jackdaw Thank you for answer. I want to use textbox instead of textblock.

Comment: What you can do is to write a ControlTemplate for your TextBox, but internally you end up using something different for displaying the text

Answer (score 1):

I believe this functionality is already built in:

```
<TextBox SpellCheck.IsEnabled="True" />
```

Comment: I already know that. You don't understand what I question.

Answer (score -1):

With a ControlTemplate you can "fake" a Richtextbox as a Textbox

```
        <TextBox Text="Foobar">
            <TextBox.Template>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                    <RichTextBox>
                        <FlowDocument>
                            <Paragraph>
                                <Run Text="{TemplateBinding Text}"></Run>
                            </Paragraph>
                        </FlowDocument>
                    </RichTextBox>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </TextBox.Template>
        </TextBox>
```

Comment: That's a really good idea. But i want to know if there is a function in textbox, not template